# Why does echoing the input from a php file that has been read only print on a single line?

Tags: php, html, parsing

First I am trying to store the parsed info from the file separated by the comma on each line into it's own object. So from the example text below each object would have two properties [some text, here] and [other text, there]

However, before I can even do that I need to access a single line. It seems that the code I am using will only output the data read in on a single line. I am sure it's something simple I am missing. Is there a way to retrieve each line individually in PHP?

```
$file = new SplFileObject("/test5.txt");

while(!$file->eof())
  {
    echo $file->fgets()."<br/>";
  }

$file = null;
```

[image: text file being read]
[image: output from code]

Comment: I don't know if this is helpful, but according to the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), "Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the [auto_detect_line_endings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.auto-detect-line-endings) run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem."

Comment: I am misunderstanding your actual question. $file->fgets() will return the contents of the file line by line, with `\n` for line breaks. Did you want to read the whole file at once and then output with `echo nl2br($file_contents)`?

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you that helped!